# Best way to define a subarray of state with consideration of react/destructuring-assignment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I'd like to define an new array containing two values of state. This array will be send to the api. My first approach which was working fine, at first, was:

```
const userRoles = {
  userName: this.state.userName,
  roles: this.state.userRoles
};
putData('api/User/EditUserRoles', userRoles).then((result) => {
  const responseJson = result;
  if (responseJson) {
    this.setState({ msg: "User's roles updated successfully!" });
  }
});
```

but after i've enabled **eslint - react/destructuring-assignment** the following errors appeared:

1. (property) userName: string Must use destructuring state
   [assignmenteslintreact/destructuring-assignment](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md)
2. (property) userRoles: string[]
   Must use destructuring state [assignmenteslintreact/destructuring-assignment](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md)

so i changed the code to

```
const { userName, userRoles } = this.state;
const userNameBuffer = userName;
const userRolesBuffer = userRoles;
const userRolesArrayBuffer = {
  userName: userNameBuffer,
  roles: userRolesBuffer
};
putData('api/User/EditUserRoles', userRolesArrayBuffer).then((result) => {
  const responseJson = result;
  if (responseJson) {
    this.setState({ msg: "User's roles updated successfully!" });
  }
});
```

which workes, but i'm not happy about using the additional "buffer" variables. Is there a way to write this code more "handsome" (e.g. no "buffer" variables) with consideration of react/destructuring-assignment?

Thank you for every answer and sorry for any mistakes in my english that may occur.

Comment: Linters exist to aid you, but not all of the lint rules have to be followed blindly. "Learn the rules so you can break them effectively."

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to save vars in buffer, more elegant and common way is:

```
const { userName, userRoles } = this.state;
const userRolesBuffer = {
  userName, // its not mistake, in object variables with same name can be assigned like this
  roles: userRoles
};
putData('api/User/EditUserRoles', userRolesBuffer).then((result) => {
  const responseJson = result;
  if (responseJson) {
    this.setState({ msg: "User's roles updated successfully!" });
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh jesus, I thought it's necessary to define the array like { userName: userName } so the return of JSON.stringify(obj); will look like { userName: value }, but {userName} seems to be enough to obtain this result.
Well, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer seems pretty easy and i misunderstood something.

I thought it's necessary to declare an array like

```
const exampleArray = {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2"
}
```

that the result of JSON.stringify(exampleArray); looks like

```
{
     "key1": "value1",
     "key2": "value2"
}
```

but it seems like that

```
const key1 = "value1";
const key2 = "value2";
const exampleArray = {
      key1,
      key2,
}
```

does return the the same result...

so my code, matching react/destructuring-assignment finally looks like

```
const { userName, userRoles } = this.state;
const roles = userRoles;
putData('api/User/EditUserRoles', { userName, roles }).then((result) => {
  const responseJson = result;
  if (responseJson) {
    this.setState({ msg: "User's roles updated successfully!" });
  }
});
```

Thank you for your answers... especially Pavlo Demydiuk ^^